# Serving static files on subpage causes 404 everywhere in nginx

Tags: nginx, docker

I have a Docker container with Nginx serving a static SPA website at `/`.
Here's the full configuration (`/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`):

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

Now, I need to change that the application is not served on `/` but on `/app` (no root at all for now). This seemed trivial so I've changed `location / {` to `location /app/ {`, but it doesn't work and now I get 404 for both `/` and `/app/`.

The new config file looks like below:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location /app/ {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

Only small change but nothing works now. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Server logs:

```
2022/06/30 12:57:29 [error] 31#31: *1 open() "/etc/nginx/html/app" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.17.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /app HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8000"
172.17.0.1 - - [30/Jun/2022:12:57:29 +0000] "GET /app HTTP/1.1" 404 555 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
2022/06/30 12:57:29 [error] 31#31: *1 open() "/etc/nginx/html/favicon.ico" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.17.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8000", referrer: "http://localhost:8000/app"
172.17.0.1 - - [30/Jun/2022:12:57:29 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 555 "http://localhost:8000/app" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
2022/06/30 12:57:30 [error] 31#31: *1 open() "/etc/nginx/html/app" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.17.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /app HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8000"
172.17.0.1 - - [30/Jun/2022:12:57:30 +0000] "GET /app HTTP/1.1" 404 555 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
2022/06/30 12:57:30 [error] 31#31: *1 open() "/etc/nginx/html/favicon.ico" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.17.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8000", referrer: "http://localhost:8000/app"
172.17.0.1 - - [30/Jun/2022:12:57:30 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 555 "http://localhost:8000/app" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

In the logs I see that it tries to get the app from `/etc/nginx/html` instead of `/usr/share/nginx/html`. I have the `root` property set to `/usr/share/nginx/html`, why it tries to get these files from `/etc`? If I move my site to `/etc/nginx/html` it works.

Comment: what does the development Mode of the browser say, which path is used and furthermore, provide logs

Comment: @djdomi - updated with the server logs

Comment: What exactly your SPA is? What technology is it built upon? And no, serving something under an URI prefix isn't trivial in any way, and may require you to change your web app settings or rebuild it completely.

Comment: @IvanShatsky - I'm aware of the required changes. I meant that changing the webserver setting should be trivial in this case. For the app, you can assume that it is just a single HTML page with no CSS / JS - just a static page.

Comment: Ok, then at least 1) put your app at the `/usr/share/nginx/html/app` directory; 2) change your `try_files` directive to `try_files $uri $uri/ /app/index.html;` (most likely `try_files $uri /app/index.html;``$uri/` should be enough). You app assets should be referred using relative links (e.g. `assets/style.css` or `./assets/style.css` instead of `/assets/style.css`) or use an URI prefix (e.g. `/app/assets/style.css`).

Comment: @IvanShatsky - I've found the solution and answered the question. The solution was different from your suggestion, you may take a look if you're curious.

Comment: The most worse solution I ever seen. If you don't want to put your app under the `/usr/share/nginx/html/app` folder (and nginx will automatically redirect `/app` to `/app/`), you can add that redirect manually (`location = /app { return 301 /app/; }` Never use regexes when you can avoid them.

Comment: The problem is that nginx also needs to redirect to `index.html` in case of 404, as the web application should handle 404 errors. This is the only configuration that works for me if you have better then post it as an answer. I've tried your solution and I must've doing something wrong as it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem, had to slightly change the configuration:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;

    location /app/ {
        alias /usr/share/nginx/html;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    }

    location ~ ^/app(.*) {
                root /usr/share/nginx/html;
                try_files $1 $1/ /index.html =404;
        }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

First - I needed the `root` attribute on the top level, then the `index.html` was loaded fine, but everything else (like `favicon.png`) was also returned with the content of `index.html`, therefore the second `location` with `~ ^/app(.*)`. I suspect that there should be better solution for it, but this one works well for me.